# Dummy values from a list as a dummy column

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to provide a list of ids to a dummy column. This will help me in identifying those ids that are not present in a table. 
Example: I would like to generate hardcoded dataset below with 'WITH' clause

```
ID
12345
23456
34567
```

Is this possible in Oracle?

Answer (score 6):

You could use a collection; if you have fewer than 32k entries the [built-in `ODCINumberList`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADDCI/ext_types_ref.htm#ADDCI5012) would do:

```
select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(12345, 23456, 34567));

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
       12345
       23456
       34567
```

Or as a CTE if you prefer:

```
with cte (id) as (
  select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(12345, 23456, 34567))
)
select * from cte;

        ID
----------
     12345
     23456
     34567
```

It's a bit easier than maintaining a large number of `union all` statements, as long as you only need one dimension. It could also be passed in to a query or procedure from an application layer as a collection - for instance you can convert a Java array to a collection that's passed through JDBC.

But if you have a lot of values, that aren't being supplied at run-time by some external mechanism, then they should probably be in a table somewhere.

Comment: You can use a materialize hint, which will significantly improve performance if you are referencing the CTE as where criteria or reference it repeatedly: `with cte (id) as ( select /*+ MATERIALIZE */* from...`

Comment: @AaronLS - I'd be wary of using an undocumented hint in production code though. (I use it [in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52523611/266304) recently to show it did have an effect, but only to prove a point *8-) I'm not sure it would actually help here as there is no real table access in the CTE, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: It does help, in my case I had multiple queries referencing the same static list with an `where id in (1,2,3)` clause, and I wanted to pull the list out into CTE so I wouldn't have to modify it everywhere.  Performance was awful and adding the hint got it back to original performance similar to inline literals.

Answer (score 3):

Does this do what you want?

```
with ids as (
      select 12345 as id from dual union all
      select 23456 from dual union all
      select 34567 from dual
     )
select ids.*
from ids;
```

There are other ways to express this.  However, the simple `union all` is the simplest method for a short list.

Comment: I have a rather large list. Could you please offer an alternative where I can hardcode the list of values?