# What is the order of execution of a function in an sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle

If I build my own function "myfunction" and this query:

```
select
myfunction(parameters)
from
mytable
where
a and b and c and d
```

if mytable has 1 million lines, but after my where I have only 100 lines.
When I had executed this query, myfunction will be executed for 100 or 1 million lines?

and in this case what happens?

```
select
myfunction(parameters)
from
mytable
where
a and b and c and d and myfunction(parameters) == e
```

Comment: If I want to execute the function only for the 100 rows, then should I first run the main query and then apply the function to the results? using select myfunction from (select ...) or using the with clause?

Comment: Yes. Don't put it in the WHERE clause if you can avoid it. Functions in the SELECT clause only get run once for every row the query returns. Functions in the WHERE clause can run as much as once for every row in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example it will only be executed 100 times. You can verify that by adding a debugging call in the function:

```
create table mytable (a, b) as select mod(level, 10), level from dual connect by level <= 50;

create or replace function myfunction(p number)
return number as
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('In function for p=' || p);
  return mod(p,3);
end;
/

set serveroutput on

select myfunction(b)
from mytable
where a = 1;

MYFUNCTION(B)
-------------
            1
            2
            0
            1
            2

In function for p=1
In function for p=11
In function for p=21
In function for p=31
In function for p=41
```

The function is only called for the rows that match the `where` clause filter. However, as far as I know that isn't guaranteed.

It's rather more complicated in the second example, and is largely up to the optimiser. For my simple demo the optimiser (11gR2 in this case) is evaluating `a` first, and only calls the function for the rows that match that; but it then calls it again for the select-list value:

```
select myfunction(b)
from mytable
where a = 1
and myfunction(b) = 2;

MYFUNCTION(B)
-------------
            2
            2

In function for p=1
In function for p=11
In function for p=11
In function for p=21
In function for p=31
In function for p=41
In function for p=41
```

The function is called for each of the five rows where `a=1` as before, and for those where `myfunction(b) = 2` it is called a second time, to get the value in the result set.

Again, for this example, things you might think would change this behaviour don't. All of these get exactly the same output:

```
select myfunction(b)
from mytable
where myfunction(b) = 2
and a = 1;

select x
from (
  select myfunction(b) as x
  from mytable
  where a = 1
)
where x = 2;

select x
from (
  select /*+ materialize */ myfunction(b) as x
  from mytable
  where a = 1
)
where x = 2;

with t (x) as (
  select myfunction(b)
  from mytable
  where a = 1
)
select x
from t
where x = 2;
```

The optimiser is internally rewriting them all into the same query, and you still get all seven function calls. Adding an undocumented hint does change it:

```
with t (x) as (
  select /*+ materialize */ myfunction(b)
  from mytable
  where a = 1
)
select x
from t
where x = 2;

         X
----------
         2
         2

In function for p=1
In function for p=11
In function for p=21
In function for p=31
In function for p=41
```

but you can't (or shouldn't) really use or rely on that.

The indexing, partitioning, the optimiser version, stats, etc. will all affect how the optimiser behaves for *your* query.

And as other things to consider, you could have a function-based index, or a deterministic function...

So... it depends.

Comment: Of course, for the example EXACTLY as given, you can avoid double execution of the function on each row by selecting 2, not myfunction(parameters), in the SELECT clause! Since the WHERE clause guarantees the value of the function will be 2 for all rows selected, there is no reason to use the function and not the constant value in SELECT.

Comment: Also for the first example I believe it is guaranteed that the function is only calculated for the rows included in the output. This should be "guaranteed" by the order of evaluation of clauses - SELECT expressions are only calculated after the other clauses (except ORDER BY) have been calculated, and only for the rows that make it into the output. It can't be any other way - SELECT may include aggregate functions, or analytic functions - all depend on which rows are in the output in the first place. (Of course, what Oracle - and the SQL Standard - guarantees is not always guaranteed...) :-)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've seen the order of evaluation described and stated in various places, but not in official documentation. So that line is just to cover myself for if/when someone (I was half expecting it to be you *8-) provides a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

The order of execution doesn't really mean anything in SQL in general, and particularly not in a sophisticated database such as Oracle.  What actually gets run is a directed acyclic graph, that represents operators such as "nested loops" and "index range scan".  These are operators you don't directly see in a SQL statement.

So, you need to be prepared for that function to be called 100 times or 1,000,000 times.  And, under different circumstances, Oracle may choose either.

As for the `where` clause, it is best not to repeat the function call.  In Oracle 12C, I would use a lateral join.  In earlier versions, a CTE or subquery should convey that the function is not called an additional time for the `where`.

Answer (score 1):

SQL has no order of execution. Is a declarative language. Ultimately, the only correct 'order' is the one described in the actual execution plan. See [Displaying Execution Plans by Using SQL Server Profiler Event Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190233(v=sql.105)/Displaying%20Execution%20Plans%20by%20Using%20SQL%20Server%20Profiler%20Event%20Classes) and Displaying Graphical Execution Plans (SQL Server Management Studio).

A completely different thing though is how do queries, subqueries and expressions project themselves into 'validity'. For instance if you have an aliased expression in the SELECT projection list, can you use the alias in the WHERE clause? Like this:

```
SELECT col1+col2 as col3
```

FROM t
WHERE col3=...;

Knowing the order in which an SQL query is executed can help us a great deal in optimizing our queries. This is especially true with large and complex queries where knowing the order of execution can save us from unwanted results, and help us create queries that execute faster.

[SEE The Execution oF Where,ON,Group By](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/what-is-the-order-of-execution-of-an-sql-query)

Kindly avoid using function in where clause it will be checked for every record in the table.

Answer (score 1):

In your second query **Where** clause will always be executed 1,000,000 times, however it can be skipped if a previous condition discards its execution at the optimizer, for example at the following example ***myfunction*** won't be executed at all.

```
select *
from mytable
where a and b and c and d and 1=0 and myfunction(parameters) == e
```

This behaviour occurs because the optimizer detects that a "false" condition has been reached so there's no need to execute **any** other condition.

**--- First query ---**

```
select myfunction(parameters)
from mytable
where a and b and c and d
```

***myfunction*** will be executed **after** your where clause, so if you query returns only 100 records it'll be executed 100 times.

**--- Second query ---**

```
select myfunction(parameters)
from mytable
where a and b and c and d and myfunction(parameters) == e
```

first ***myfunction*** will be executed two times one at your **select** clause and also at your **where** clause, so if you query returns only 100 records it'll be executed 100 times. but for your second **myfuntion** call it'll be executed ***1 million times***.

Best way to avoid that ***1 million*** function execution in oracle it's the [***MATERIALIZE***](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_materialize_sql_hint.htm) hint and a ***WITH*** query, the following query should return the same results as your second query:

```
with hundred_records as (
    select /*+ MATERIALIZE */ myfunction(parameters) fn_result, mytable.*
    from mytable
    where a and b and c and d
)
select *
from mytable
where fn_result = e
```

However i strongly recommend you to add a column inside ***mytable*** to store the ***myfunction*** result in it, you will save your self a lot of performance issues doing that. You'll have to update that column everytime you know **"parameters"** had changed.